# EU resident traveling to UK with French spouse

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, france, eu, eu-citizens

I am a resident of France and want to visit a family member in the UK who is quite ill. I will be traveling with my spouse who is French.
Do I need a visa? I read online about an EU family permit but am not able to find any links to apply for it.
[image]

Comment: To answer we need to know your citizenship. Residency in France and/or (post-Brexit) having a French spouse does not in itself mean you can enter the UK without a visa. Have you checked the advice tool published by the UK https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa?

Comment: Eligibility criteria for a family permit and how to apply are here https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/apply-joining-family-member-eu-switzerland-norway-iceland-liechtenstein However, based on your question you most probably don’t qualify.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I did use the tool to check and it says I won't need a visa if the person I'm traveling with is a EU citizen. But like you pointed out, I'm quite doubtful still, that's why I put up a question here.  I'm an indian citizen. Quote directly after using the advice tool " When you might not need a visa
You may be able to apply to come to the UK for free instead of paying for a visa if your partner or family member is a British citizen or from another European country." I don't know where to apply for this particular visa? Is it tourist visa or something else?

Comment: You can check if you’re eligible for a family permit to **join family** in the UK here https://www.gov.uk/family-permit. The section relating to EEA family permits on that page states that applying for an EEA family permit is no longer possible. Therefore, based on the info in your question, you’ll need a visitor visa.